# closing the sidenav by clicking enywhere outside the sidenav

Tags: javascript, html

I want to Close the sidenav by clicking anywhere outside sidenav
my html code is

```
<body>
<!-- show image while loading -->
<div class="se-pre-con"></div>
<!-- Header starts here -->
<div class = "header">
    <!-- search bar -->
    <?php include("header.php");?>
    <!-- search bar ends here -->
</div>
<!-- header ends here -->

<div class="primary" id="primary">
    <!-- image slider starts here -->
    <div class="image-slider">
        <?php include("slider.php");?>
    </div>
    <!-- image slider starts here -->

    <!-- all-content starts here -->
    <div class = "container wraper">

        <!-- content starts here -->
        <div class="content">
            <h3 class="Category"><strong> Category </strong>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-xs btn-success complete" id="more"><strong>More </strong> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-forward"></button>
            </h3><hr id="index-hr">
            <?php include("functions/index_category.php"); ?>
        </div>
        <!-- content ends here -->

    </div>
    <!-- all-content ends here-->

        <!-- daily adds starts here -->
    <div class="container news">
        <h3 class="news"><strong> Daily News </strong></h3><hr id="index-hr">
    </div>
        <!-- daily adds ends here -->

    <!-- side nav starts here -->
    <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
        <div id="result">
        <?php include("functions/sub_category.php")?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- side nav ends here -->
</div>
</body>
```

The Js i tried :

```
//close the side nav when clicked outside
 var primary = document.getElementById('primary');
 var sidenav = document.getElementById('mySidenav');
 window.onclick = function(event){
     if( event.target == primary ){
        sidenav.style.width = "0px";
        primary.style.marginLeft = "0px";
     }
 }
```

How ever it works  clicking enywhere on the side nav by replacing event.target == sidenav But i want to close it by clickng outside

js for opening and closing the side nav are

```
function openNav() {
    if($(window).width() > 600){
        $("#mySidenav").attr("style","width:350px");
        $(".primary").attr("style","margin-left:350px");
    }else{
        $("#mySidenav").attr("style","width:100%");
        $(".primary").attr("style","margin-left:100%");
    }

}

function closeNav() {
    $("#mySidenav").attr("style","width:0px");
    $(".primary").attr("style","margin-left:0px");
}
```

css code:

```
.wraper{
    min-height: 165px;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 200px;
}
.content {
    margin-top: 30px;
}
#more{
    width:6%;
    margin-right:0px;
    float:right;
}
.wraper.complete{
    height: auto;
}
h3.sub{
    color:#d34615;
    text-decoration:underline;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
#index-hr{
    width:100%;
    border-top:1px solid #333;
    opacity:0.3;
}
```

Comment: what happens now?

Comment: Now it wont close when i click on primary

Answer (score 0):

Just check the `event.target` to see if it was NOT the side nav and that the nav is NOT already open:

```
//close the side nav when clicked outside
 var primary = document.getElementById('primary');
 var sidenav = document.getElementById('mySidenav');

 window.onclick = function(event){

     var sideNavWidth = sidenav.style.width;

     // check to see if the event target was not the side nav
     // AND that the side nav is open
     if( event.target !== sidenav && sideNavWidth !== "0" ){
        sidenav.style.width = "0";
        primary.style.marginLeft = "0";
     }
 }
```

This is a crude implementation of your code, but you can see that the side nav bar does, in fact open (yellow) and will not close if you click on it, but will close if you click anywhere else.

```js
//close the side nav when clicked outside
 var primary = document.getElementById('primary');
 var sidenav = document.getElementById('mySidenav');

 window.onclick = function(event){

     var sideNavWidth = sidenav.style.width;

     // check to see if the event target was not the side nav
     // AND that the side nav is open
     if( event.target !== sidenav && sideNavWidth !== "0" ){
         closeNav();
     }
 }
 
 function closeNav(){
          sidenav.style.width = "0";
        primary.style.marginLeft = "0";
 }
```

```css
.sidenav { background: yellow;}
```

```html
<div class="primary" id="primary">
    <!-- image slider starts here -->
    <div class="image-slider">
        <?php include("slider.php");?>
    </div>
    <!-- image slider starts here -->

    <!-- all-content starts here -->
    <div class = "container wraper">

        <!-- content starts here -->
        <div class="content">
            <h3 class="Category"><strong> Category </strong>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-xs btn-success complete" id="more"><strong>More </strong> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-forward"></button>
            </h3><hr id="index-hr">
            <?php include("functions/index_category.php"); ?>
        </div>
        <!-- content ends here -->

    </div>
    <!-- all-content ends here-->

        <!-- daily adds starts here -->
    <div class="container news">
        <h3 class="news"><strong> Daily News </strong></h3><hr id="index-hr">
    </div>
        <!-- daily adds ends here -->

    <!-- side nav starts here -->
    <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
        <div id="result">
        <?php include("functions/sub_category.php")?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- side nav ends here -->
</div>
```

Comment: tried...But in that case the side nav does not open in first place

Comment: @Mps See my updated answer. Also, FYI: when setting a CSS size to 0, a unit of measurment ("px") is not required.

Comment: with your updated answer in which u used event.target !== sidenav, again brings mw to the same problem where the side nav itself doen't open. please check the html code once i'm guessing problem may be in there...as primary contain other div elements

Comment: @Mps But, with the added condition, the side nav will only close if it is already open.

Comment: Yeah..! but as i told already when i put the condition as  event.target !== sidenav or  event.target != sidenav the side nav is not opening

Comment: i dont know what is preventing it from opening..i have tried ur code and still the same...i really really appreciate ur help

Comment: the css of other element is causing the problem..even though i couldn't solve it but now i'm sure the way used the css for design id causing the problem..the js code i shown above actually works...but after 100's of clicks in different positions  it is closing once